# RecyclerView doesn't show any items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I wish to create a scrollable bunch of items from weather reports by using an `Adapter` and a `RecyclerView`. My problem is that even though the `ArrayList<>` I use to provide data **does have data**, the view just doesn't show anything - and no errors, no crashes. The app starts and nothing to show.

My `ActivityMain.onCreate()`:

```
private JSONParser_basic parser;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    parser = new JSONParser_basic(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.weather_json));

    parser.divideToListElements();

    NewsRecycleAdapter adapter = new NewsRecycleAdapter(parser.getListElements());
    LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    lm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    rv.setLayoutManager(lm);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Note that the `JSONParser_basic` is a self-made simple class (out of practice, to get data from a specific string). I use it to get data from a JSON string and load it to my collection `listElements`. It does its job, I get the data, that isn't the issue.

My `News` class:

```
public class News {

    private String max;
    private String min;
    private String weather;
    private String windForce;

    public News(String max, String min, String weather, String windForce) {
        this.max = max;
        this.min = min;
        this.weather = weather;
        this.windForce = windForce;
    }

    public String formReport(){
        return max + "/" + min + ", "
                 + weather + ", " +
                "Wind=" + windForce;
    }
}
```

I uploaded this class to show the `formReport` method.

My adapter:

```
public class NewsRecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsRecycleAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

    List<News> items;

    public NewsRecycleAdapter(List<News> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)     
    {
        return new NewsViewHolder(View.inflate(parent.getContext(),
                R.layout.list_element,
                null));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        News myNews = items.get(position);
        holder.titleTV.setText(myNews.formReport());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items == null ? 0 : items.size();
    }

    public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView titleTV, leadTV;
        public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titleTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }


}
```

The `list_element.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="7dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"

    android:text="some gibberish for now"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

And finally my `main_activity.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.smth.myname.jeeesoooon.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

And I **do have** this line in my app's `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.+'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is the `RecyclerView` height and width `0dp` ?

Change it to the following:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Also, in `list_element.xml`, change the layout height to `wrap_content`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Heh why I put 0dp there, it's a mystery. Now it works just fine, thanks for the advice. 
Well I made a noobish mistake, if I'm to say so meself.